# JavaScriptSerializer removes Identifyer (ID)

Tags: c#

When i run the code below, It seems to remove 2 of my propperties, and i really need them for my jquery code to run correctly.

```
List<UserInformation> ui = OrgChartDataProvider.Instance.GetTree(username).ToList();

System.Web.Script.Serialization.JavaScriptSerializer oSerializer = new System.Web.Script.Serialization.JavaScriptSerializer();

var ds = oSerializer.Serialize(ui);
```

---

This is what my `UserInformation` looks like

```
public int Id { get; set; }
public int? parentId { get; set; }
public string Name { get; set; }
public string Title { get; set; }
public string Department { get; set; }
public string Image { get; set; }
public string Parent { get; set; }
public string Username { get; set; }
public string Company { get; set; }
public string Initials { get; set; }
public bool Disabled { get; set; }
```

---

This is what I get when i console.log(ds) in jquery:

```
Company : "Dovista"
Department : "Silver office"
Disabled : false
Image : "/_layouts/15/dovista.intranet/Images/Images/1486993286_user_male2.png"
Initials : "BOJ"
Name : "BOSS JONAS"
Parent : "RPR"
Title : "Main boss"
Username : "BOJ"
```

It looks like my 2 `int`'s are not included, what can i do to keep those?

Comment: Check your list variable ui. Is it there?

Comment: @Amit yes it is

Comment: This is working fine for me in a console app.